# Suppress 'note' field if empty from custom endnote in Image Credits page

Tags: biblatex, citing, ifthenelse

I have an Image Credits page where I cite images using standard citations in a bib file. I use the 'note' field to report licensing information. Sometimes this field is empty and then the word '**note**' is printed at the end of my reference.

Is there some way to capture that this field is empty, and print nothing?

I have tried multiple variations on

```
\if\relax\citefield{sibswissinstituteofbioinformaticsQ8WZ42TITIN_HUMANHomo}{note}\relax
\else
\citefield{sibswissinstituteofbioinformaticsQ8WZ42TITIN_HUMANHomo}{note}
\fi
```

including \empty, {note} as second parameter in different permutations, etc., with absolutely no luck, and don't know where to go next.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@artwork{galbraithStandardModelPhysics,
    title = {Standard model of physics},
    url = {https://texample.net/tikz/examples/model-physics/},
    author = {Galbraith, David and Burgard, Carsten},
    note = {Adapted slightly from original. Used under the terms of the Creative Commons {CC} {BY} Deed 2.5 License},
}

@artwork{sibswissinstituteofbioinformaticsQ8WZ42TITIN_HUMANHomo,
    title = {Q8WZ42 ({TITIN}\_HUMAN) Homo sapiens (Human)},
    url = {https://swissmodel.expasy.org/repository/uniprot/Q8WZ42},
    abstract = {note: added a period in "Extra" because something is needed here for {\textbackslash}citeimage to work properly, and this lines up with the ... dots following},
    author = {{SIB Swiss Institute of Bioinformatics}},
    urldate = {2024-01-04},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside,table]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


% custom image credits list; file extension .imc

\newlistof{imagecredits}{imc}{Image Credits}
\newcommand{\addtoimagecredits}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \citeimage {o m} {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \addcontentsline{imc}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\addtoimagecredits}\citetitle{#2} by \citename{#2}{author}, retrieved from \citeurl{#2}. \citefield{#2}{note}}
    }{%
        \addcontentsline{imc}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\addtoimagecredits}[#1] \citetitle{#2} by \citename{#2}{author}, retrieved from \citeurl{#2}. \citefield{#2}{note}}
    }%
}


\begin{document}
    \citeimage{sibswissinstituteofbioinformaticsQ8WZ42TITIN_HUMANHomo}
    \citeimage{galbraithStandardModelPhysics}

    \citefield{sibswissinstituteofbioinformaticsQ8WZ42TITIN_HUMANHomo}{note}
    
    \citefield{galbraithStandardModelPhysics}{note}

    
    \imagecredits
\end{document}
```

BTW - I have tried other endnote packages including enotez but these don't play nice with some of other packages I use - and I don't know that would make a difference